# Logic error in my C code

Tags: c, logic

I have the following method that reads in two strings to change the first and last names of two entries in a database. The name is always converted to lowercase, and should only take in names with letters or hyphen on them, unless the hyphen is the first or last character in the string. On an error, it just prompts the user again.

```
/*
Prompts for a student name, and checks if input is correct.
Returns 0 on success, -1 onEOF.
If the user inputs an invalid entry, the error is ignored and the user is simply asked again.
*/
int get_name(char *first, char *last)
{
char input[LINESIZE];
char buffer[LINESIZE];
char buffer2[LINESIZE];
int i;

while (1)
{
    printf("\n%s", "Enter the Student Name    ");
    if (!fgets(input, LINESIZE, stdin))
    {
        clearerr(stdin);
        return -1;
    }
    if (sscanf(input, "%s %s", buffer, buffer2) == 2)
    {
        if (strlen(buffer) < 20 && strlen(buffer2) < 20 && strlen(buffer) >= 2 && strlen(buffer2) >= 2) /*checks to see if the length is at least 2, but less than 20*/
        {
            for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) /*checks every character on the string, converts it to lower and then checks if it's a letter or a hyphen, restarts if not.*/
            {
                if (isalpha(buffer[i]))
                {
                    buffer[i] = tolower(buffer[i]);
                }
                if (isalpha(buffer2[i]))
                {
                    buffer2[i] = tolower(buffer2[i]);
                }
                if (!isalpha(buffer[i]) && buffer[i] != '-')
                {
                    break;
                }
                if (!isalpha(buffer2[i]) && buffer2[i] != '-')
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (buffer[0] == '-' || buffer[(strlen(buffer) - 1)] == '-')
            {
                i = 0;
            }
            if (buffer2[0] == '-' || buffer2[(strlen(buffer2) - 1)] == '-')
            {
                i = 0;
            }
            if (i == 20)
            {
                sscanf(buffer, "%s", first);
                sscanf(buffer2, "%s", last);
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I have tracked down the error to the lines with `(!isalpha(buffer[i]) && buffer[i] != '-')`, but I can't figure out why the statement is wrong.

So for example, an succesful input can be "john smith", or "Hom-er simpson". In both of these cases, the function should return 0 (succesful).
If the input is something like: "Denny's White", "-alexa redfield", "albert" or "1234 5647" the function should just start over (prompting the user again). 
At the moment, no matter the input, the function starts over.

Comment: Please show an example input, intended output, and actual output.

Comment: Without comments, it's really hard to tell what parts of this code are intended to do. For example, why are you testing if `i` reached 20? What do you think that is doing? And what do you think those two `scanf` calls at the end do? What is the intended purpose of the two `break` statements?

Comment: my bad, I will edit the post to add more comments. The reason I'm checking if i == 20 is because I intended the for loop to check if each character in the string is not a letter or a hyphen. If the for loop runs successfully then it would stop at i = 20, which means that there are no issues with the input and can return 0 (which means the method succeeded).
The sscanf makes the first = to buffer, and last = buffer2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **main** logic error in your program is the fact that you are running a `for` loop with a fixed number (20) of iterations on two arrays **at the same time**. You should run two separate loops for first and last name arrays. Also, you should run these two loops for only `strlen` of each array. See the following sample:

```
for (i = 0; i < strlen(buffer); i++)
{
    /* your existing stuff for the "buffer" */
}

for (i = 0; i < strlen(buffer1); i++)
{
    /* your existing stuff for the "buffer1" */
}
```

Comment: @WeatherVane, thanks for your inputs. "@ snow", please read this too.

Comment: Thank you so much! My program is working as intended now. I changed the i in the second for loop to a j, since it needs to check at the end that both loops were successful.
Also, on Weather Vane's reply, I'm not sure what that means?

Comment: @WeatherVane I see. Would this be as simple as saying `buffer[strlen(buffer)] = '/0'`, or is it something much more complex?

Comment: @Snow my misread of the code, sorry, you are altering characters in a string that was already made. But `buffer[strlen(buffer)] = '\0'` will never work, since `strlen` relies on the terminator being present anyway.

Comment: Splitting the loops is the way to go. But, now, OP needs a separate flag variable for success/fail because `i==20` was the prior success criterion.

Comment: @CraigEstey my success criterion is now `i == strlen(buffer) && j == strlen(buffer2)`, it seems to be working properly.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for your help anyway, I will keep it mind in the future.

Answer (score 0):

*Caveat:* VHS got the main problem. But, this also points out a structural issue in your code that can be improved. Almost all the code is duplicated for each array.

Creating a function to operate on the array would have [probably] made it easier to see the issue.

I've reworked your code to add this [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define LINESIZE    80

int
bufdo(char *buf)
{
    int len;
    int idx;
    int chr;
    int ret;

    len = strlen(buf);

    do {
        // assume non-conforming
        ret = -1;

        // length too great
        if (len >= 20)
            break;

        // length too small
        if (len < 2)
            break;

        // begins with hyphen
        if (buf[0] == '-')
            break;

        // ends with hyphen
        if (buf[len - 1] == '-')
            break;

        // assume it will be okay
        ret = len;

        // convert to lowercase and check for bad chars
        for (idx = 0;  idx < len;  ++idx) {
            chr = buf[idx];

            if (isalpha(chr)) {
                chr = tolower(chr);
                buf[idx] = chr;
                continue;
            }

            // non-hyphen char in name
            if (chr != '-') {
                ret = -1;
                break;
            }
        }
    } while (0);

    return ret;
}

int
get_name(char *first, char *last)
{

    char input[LINESIZE];
    char buffer[LINESIZE];
    char buffer2[LINESIZE];
    int len1;
    int len2;
    int ret;

    ret = -1;

    while (1) {
        printf("\n%s", "Enter the Student Name    ");
        fflush(stdout);

        if (!fgets(input, LINESIZE, stdin)) {
            clearerr(stdin);
            break;
        }

        if (sscanf(input, "%s %s", buffer, buffer2) != 2)
            continue;

        len1 = bufdo(buffer);
        len2 = bufdo(buffer2);

        if ((len1 > 0) && (len2 > 0)) {
            strcpy(first,buffer);
            strcpy(last,buffer2);
            ret = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is definitely way neater.

Comment: You're welcome! Note that I built up the function piecemeal. Originally, I called it `getlen` and it just did `strlen` and the length range check. I was going to create other funcs for the other steps, but added the other stages/steps one at a time when I realized they would "fit" nicely in the function. So, in the end, the single function was sufficient. A good rule of thumb is to consider "scale" (i.e. does my code _scale_ well [enough]?). With some more experience, these design choices will become easier to see and [almost] axiomatic. Happy Programming!